# How to scrape a website using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website https://remittanceprices.worldbank.org/en/corridor/Australia/China for Fee  field.

```
url = 'https://remittanceprices.worldbank.org/en/corridor/Australia/China'
r = requests.get(url,verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
rows = [i.get_text("|").split("|") for i in soup.select('#tab-1 .corridor-row')]
for row in rows:
    #a,b,c,d,e = row[2],row[15],row[18],row[21],row[25]
    #print(a,b,c,d,e,sep='|')
    print('{0[2]}|{0[15]}|{0[18]}|{0[21]}|{0[25]}').format(row)
```

But I am receiving a response AttributeError with the above code.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `.format()` with `print()`, not the string. `.format()` is a method of `str` type and `print()` actually returns `None`, so try:

```
url = 'https://remittanceprices.worldbank.org/en/corridor/Australia/China'
r = requests.get(url,verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
rows = [i.get_text("|").split("|") for i in soup.select('#tab-1 .corridor-row')]
for row in rows:
    #a,b,c,d,e = row[2],row[15],row[18],row[21],row[25]
    #print(a,b,c,d,e,sep='|')
    print('{0[2]}|{0[15]}|{0[18]}|{0[21]}|{0[25]}'.format(row))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would like to extract "Fee" column values for all the rows. I tried with above snippet. Can you let me know how I can achieve that?